# What is the discount granted by the merit award Cheapjack?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

What is the exact discount granted by the merit award Cheapjack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discount provided is 10%. Here are some examples:

- White bread. 20g -> 18g
- Iced Coffee. 200g -> 180g.
- Phoenix Feather. 500g -> 450g.